# How to install .xpi add-on file for Firefox?

Tags: software-installation, firefox, 11.04, add-on

I just downloaded a download accelerator called SKDownloader for Firefox 4.  I successfully installed the program, but now I'm stuck at installing the accompanying add-on `.xpi` for the program to be compatible with Firefox.

In Windows, all I had to do was open the `.xpi` with Firefox and it would automatically install as an add-on. How do I install the `.xpi` file in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag'n'drop from Nautilus or whatever else to Firefox window should work too (any tab, doesn't need to be addon manager).

This way is somewhat faster if you already have found .xpi file.

Answer (score 7):

Go to tools>addons (or open addons from the firefox button, or type about:addons in your address bar and press enter).

- Now, click on the button:

  [image]
- And click install addon from file:

  [image]
- Then locate your addon in the file manager and install it :)!

Answer (score 2):

You can just open FireFox and then drag the *.xpi File to the fireFox Browser, then it will automatically open the *.xpi file.